# How to write a multiline case in latex?

Tags: equations, pdftex, cases

I am trying to get the output similar to this:

[image: First case is an equation spanning two lines.]

I have written this code:

```
\begin{equation}
\text{RHS} \rightarrow  
\begin{cases} 
\vert 1 \rangle \left[\frac{2\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + 4\beta^2}}\vert B\rangle  - \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + 4\beta^2}}\vert A \rangle\right] , &D_1\textrm{ clicks, probability $\frac{\alpha^2}{4}$}\\
\vert 2 \rangle\vert A \rangle, &D_2\textrm{ clicks, probability $\frac{\alpha^2}{4}$}\\
\vert \text{scattered} \rangle\vert A \rangle, &\textrm{ no clicks with probability $\frac{\alpha^2}{2}$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

And the following is the output:
[image: The first case becomes too long.]

How then, should I modify the code to get the output similar to first image? If I just add a line break in the first case it gives an error.

Thank you.

Comment: What image are you referring to?

Comment: Image of the output. First image, at the beginning is of the output I want.

Comment: There was no images 6min ago ;-)

Comment: Oh! They have been visible to me all along! :P

Comment: You could take a look to `physiscs` package; it offers useful `\bra` and `\ket` commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Would this hack be sufficient?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\text{RHS} \rightarrow  
\begin{cases} 
\vert 1 \rangle \bigg[\frac{2\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + 4\beta^2}}\vert B\rangle &D_1\textrm{ clicks, probability $\frac{\alpha^2}{4}$}\\
\quad - \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + 4\beta^2}}\vert A \rangle\bigg], & \\
\vert 2 \rangle\vert A \rangle, &D_2\text{ clicks, probability $\frac{\alpha^2}{4}$}\\
\vert \text{scattered} \rangle\vert A \rangle, &\text{no clicks with probability $\frac{\alpha^2}{2}$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, but can this not be done using some command similar to when we are writing multiline equations?

Answer (score 6):

The `amsmath` "subsidiary" environments are built for just this purpose. Here, I use `aligned`, using the `\vert`s inside the multi-line case expression as the alignment point. You could just as well change the alignment point to some other position, or use `gathered` if no special alignment of the expression is required.

The vertical alignment of the case conditions can be adjusted using `t` (top), `b` (bottom), or `c` (center, default) as the optional argument to the `aligned` or `gathered` environment.

Here's the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\text{RHS} \rightarrow  
\begin{cases}\!% alignment adjustment
  \begin{aligned}[b]% adjust case condition placement here, use [t]op, [b]ottom, or [c]enter (default)
    \vert 1 \rangle \bigg[\frac{2\beta}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + 4\beta^2}} &\vert B \rangle \\ 
     - \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + 4\beta^2}} &\vert A \rangle \bigg],
  \end{aligned} &\textrm{$D_1$ clicks, probability $\frac{\alpha^2}{4}$}\\
\vert 2 \rangle \vert A \rangle, &\text{$D_2$ clicks, probability $\frac{\alpha^2}{4}$}\\
\vert \text{scattered} \rangle \vert A \rangle, &\text{no clicks with probability $\frac{\alpha^2}{2}$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another option, which I tend to use when there is no clear alignment point is `multlined` environment.

Comment: @Manuel, good point! I stuck with `amsmath` environments here, but `multlined` is an equally valid choice using the `mathtools` package.